# Find Physical Location of Filegroup on SQL 2008 using TSQL

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

How can I use tsql to find the physical location of a filegroup on SQL Server 2008?

Comment: I think you might be looking for this article. [sys.master_files (Transact-SQL)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186782.aspx)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this..

```
SELECT * FROM sys.database_files
```

**OR**

```
SELECT * FROM sys.sysaltfiles
```

**Also**
Use this script to see a more detailed picture of objects and their actual physical file names and locations.

```
SELECT    OBJECT_NAME(i.id) AS Table_Name
        , i.indid           AS Index_ID
        , i.name            AS Index_Name
        , i.groupid         AS Group_ID
        , f.name            AS File_Group
        , d.physical_name   AS [File_Name]
        , s.name            AS Dataspace
FROM        sys.sysindexes      i
INNER JOIN  sys.filegroups      f   ON f.data_space_id = i.groupid
INNER JOIN  sys.database_files  d   ON f.data_space_id = d.data_space_id
INNER JOIN  sys.data_spaces     s   ON f.data_space_id = s.data_space_id
WHERE   OBJECTPROPERTY(i.id, 'IsUserTable') = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the information returned by sys.data_spaces is actually the logical rather than the physical location of data.

[sys.data_spaces and partitioning](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1548437-2799-1.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

This is what you wanted to see:

```
SELECT 
[Filegroup_Name] = fg.[name],
[DB_File_Logical_Name] = df.[name],
[DB_File_Physical_Name] = df.[physical_name]
FROM sys.filegroups fg
JOIN sys.database_files df ON df.[data_space_id] = fg.[data_space_id]
```